# Problemas con hacer un mantenimiento en java spring

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-security

Trato de incorporar un mantenimiento sencillo "Agregar usuarios" a un proyecto con *spring security* pero me salen estos errores, me estoy guiando de otro proyecto pero que funciona con ldap

```
 type Informe de Excepción

 mensaje Servlet.init() para servlet mvc-dispatcher lanzó excepción

 descripción El servidor encontró un error interno que hizo que no pudiera rellenar este requerimiento.

 excepción

 javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet.init() para servlet mvc-dispatcher lanzó excepción
org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:509)
org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1104)
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:684)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1520)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1476)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

causa raíz

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'usuarioDao': Injection of persistence dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory] is defined
org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:357)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1202)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:762)
org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:663)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:629)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:677)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:548)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:489)
org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:509)
org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1104)
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:684)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1520)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1476)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

  *causa raíz*

   org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory] is defined
org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.findDefaultEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:572)
org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.findEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:528)
org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$PersistenceElement.resolveEntityManager(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:694)
org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$PersistenceElement.getResourceToInject(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:667)
org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata$InjectedElement.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:155)
org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:354)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1202)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:762)
org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:663)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:629)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:677)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:548)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:489)
org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:509)
org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1104)
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:684)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1520)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1476)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

*Main Controller*

```
    package com.csye.sep.web.controller;

    import
    org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken;
    import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
    import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
        import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
        import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
        import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
        import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
        import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
        import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

    @Controller
     public class MainController {

     @RequestMapping(value = { "/", "/hello**" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
      public ModelAndView defaultPage() {

       ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();
       model.setViewName("login");
        return model;

         }

      @RequestMapping(value = "/inicioProyecto**", method = RequestMethod.GET)
       public ModelAndView adminPage() {

        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();
        model.setViewName("../proyecto/inicioProyecto");

        return model;

         }


          @RequestMapping(value = "/inicio**", method = RequestMethod.GET)
         public ModelAndView helloPage() {

          ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();
          model.setViewName("inicio");

          return model;

            }

       @RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public ModelAndView login(@RequestParam(value = "error", required = false) String error,
            @RequestParam(value = "logout", required = false) String logout) {

          ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();
           if (error != null) {
            model.addObject("error", "Usuario y Contraseña erroneas");
             }

           if (logout != null) {

             }
           model.setViewName("login");

           return model;

           }

           //for 403 access denied page
          @RequestMapping(value = "/403", method = RequestMethod.GET)
           public ModelAndView accesssDenied() {

          ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();

          //check if user is login
          Authentication auth =       SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
           if (!(auth instanceof AnonymousAuthenticationToken)) {
            UserDetails userDetail = (UserDetails) auth.getPrincipal();
            System.out.println(userDetail);

            model.addObject("username", userDetail.getUsername());

             }

           model.setViewName("403");
          return model;

           }

          }
```

*mvc-dis-servlet.xml*

```
          <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
          <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
          xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
          xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
          xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"        
           xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.1.xsd
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-4.1.xsd
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.1.xsd
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.1.xsd                          
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-4.1.xsd"
   default-autowire="byName">
          <mvc:annotation-driven/>   

            <context:component-scan base-package="com.csye.*" />

                <bean
       class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
             <property name="prefix">
            <value>/WEB-INF/pages/</value>
               </property>
            <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
            </property>
           </bean>
           <!--========== Mapping Exceptions ==========-->
           <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleMappingExceptionResolver">
               <property name="exceptionMappings">
                <props>
                <prop key="org.springframework.dao.DataAccessException">dataAccessFailure</prop>
                <prop key="org.springframework.transaction.TransactionException">dataAccessFailure</prop>
            </props>
            </property>
         </bean>
            <!--  Los Controllers marcados con el annotation @Controller son autodetectados  -->
         <context:component-scan base-package="com.csye.sep.web.*">
         <context:include-filter type="annotation"  expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller"/>
        </context:component-scan>

          </beans>
```

Answer (score 0):

el problema está en la parte de persistencia, me explico:

Al poner `<context:component-scan base-package="com.csye.*" />` y `<context:component-scan base-package="com.csye.sep.web.*">` spring escanea todas las clases dentro de esos paquetes, incluyendo los subpaquetes.
En este caso con solo poner `<context:component-scan base-package="com.csye.*" />` tendría el mismo efecto que poner ambas cosas.

Al realizar este escaneo, spring esta detectando clases que utilizan persistencia de datos, clases que extienden de algún tipo de repositorio para la gestión de los datos con el ldap.
Por eso spring busca `javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory`, que se encarga del manejo de las entitys.

Si tu objetivo es llegar a hacer un mantenimiento de datos, debes configurar este `javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory`, para que las clases que se encargarán de la persistencia puedan inicializarse.

Según el tipo de repositorio (persistencia) que esté usando puede valerte con cambiar el datasource, indicandole que utilize un conector para la base de datos que vayas a usar en vez de usar el conector de tipo ldap que heredas.

Si necesitas más ayuda, coméntanos. Un saludo.